# Not every bone position is saved on the pose library

Tags: animation, armature, bones, pose-mode

I'm trying to save the facial bone poses to use them later simply clicking on a button. Let's say that I would make this first pose :

[image: 1]

I started from a neutral pose and I rotated,scaled and translated the bones,so I have reached this final pose :

[image: 2]

I saved the bone positions using the pose library. When I did "apply specific pose library pose to the rig",not every pose has been set correctly. Infact,the bone called "DEF_jaw" has been ignored. I tried to place it again in the position I want,but every time it is ignored. Can someone tell me why ? Check also the attached video for a better understanding....

[what I did](https://sendvid.com/raxavhmq)

I attach also the blender file...

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was tough, but I finally found an answer for that issue. The thing is, Pose library don't save positions of bones with DEF in the beginning of their names (I don't know if it's also true for endings and middle, cause I didn't try this).So to use Pose Library, rename the bones with DEF

Comment: Yes. You are right. I tried to rename the bone to DIF_def_jaw and it didn't work. So,it does not work if "DEF" or " def " is placed somewhere inside the name. You have been very capable to fix this error. But do you think that's a bug ? If yes,we should post a bug on the apposite section ?

Comment: Anyway,the situation behind is more complex than we think. I made some tests :

A_jaw : is not accepted
AB_jaw : is not accepted
ABC_jaw : is not accepted
D_jaw : is not accepted
F_jaw : is not accepted
DIF_jaw : is accepted

I'm not able to understand what's the logic behind this behaviour